# Pytest, Verify list of files against whitelist

Tags: pytest, whitelist

We have a list of files in a project. And a whitelist. Like in the failed attempt bellow:

```
import pytest

files=["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]
whitelist=["a.txt", "q.txt", "b.txt"]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("file_name", files)
def test_that_files_are_in_whitelist():
    assert all(???)
```

I would like to make pytest complain about **c.txt that is not in the whitelist**. Are anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, no need for manual looping:

```
import pytest

files=["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]
file_whitelist=["a.txt", "q.txt", "b.txt"]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("file_name", files)
def test_that_files_are_in_whitelist(file_name):
    assert file_name in file_whitelist
```

This seems to be OK.

[image: running pytest -v]